# Variable Font 40 times larger than 'static' fonts

Tags: fonts, variable-fonts

I'm using three font weights of a 'normal' 'static' typeface. Each weight is 16KB. I've been reading how Variable Fonts are super fast to load because it is only one file. But the Variable Font version of the same typeface is 640KB. x40 the size of individual weights. (I'm using Adobe Fonts). Why all the fuss about Variable Fonts being small file sizes and fast to download? Am I missing something?

Comment: Apparently Adobe provides only the most complete font (including all unicode-ranges, axes etc.)  as a variable font. If there is no subsetting feature available you could try to create on e yourself using a tool like [fontTools](https://barrd.dev/article/create-a-variable-font-subset-for-smaller-file-size/) or request this feature. But if you don't need all axes – just take the static fonts as suggested.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to subset Google Fonts variable fonts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only one style from a font family, the static font will always be smaller than a variable font. But if you are using multiple styles from a font family, the variable font will start providing size savings. The amount of savings would depend on how many styles from the family you want to use. If you were using *five* styles from the family, you'd probably find that the variable font is perhaps 70% or more smaller than the combined sizes of the static fonts.

Comment: In my case Acumin Variable Font from Adobe Fonts is 40 times the size of a static weight. So I'd have to use more than *40* styles before the variable font was smaller! I can't find a way on Adobe Fonts to create a variable font that only has the axis or ranges I need. For example, I don't need the width axis.

Comment: @user2991837 I answered your question. You might not like the answer, but it's still the correct answer to the question that was asked.